# Regarding vector values

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Here is a code snippet below. 
Input to program is

```
dimension d[] = {{4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {10, 12, 32}};
PVecDim vecdim(new VecDim());
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]); ++i) {
        vecdim->push_back(&d[i]);
    }
getModList(vecdim);
```

Program:

```
class dimension;
typedef shared_ptr<vector<dimension*> > PVecDim;
typedef vector<dimension*> VecDim;
typedef vector<dimension*>::iterator VecDimIter;

struct dimension {
    int height, width, length;
    dimension(int h, int w, int l) : height(h), width(w), length(l) {

    }
};

PVecDim getModList(PVecDim inList) {
        PVecDim modList(new VecDim());
        VecDimIter it;

        for(it = inList->begin(); it!=inList->end(); ++it) {
            dimension rot1((*it)->length, (*it)->width, (*it)->height);
            dimension rot2((*it)->width, (*it)->height, (*it)->length);

            cout<<"rot1 "<<rot1.height<<" "<<rot1.length<<" "<<rot1.width<<endl;
            cout<<"rot2 "<<rot2.height<<" "<<rot2.length<<" "<<rot2.width<<endl;

            modList->push_back(*it);
            modList->push_back(&rot1);
            modList->push_back(&rot2);
            for(int i=0;i < 3;++i) {
                cout<<(*modList)[i]->height<<" "<<(*modList)[i]->length<<" "<<(*modList)[i]->width<<" "<<endl;
            }
        }
            return modList;
}
```

What I see is that the values rot1 and rot2 actually overwrite previous values. 
For example that cout statement prints as below for input values defined at top. Can someone tell me why are these values being overwritten?

```
rot1 7 4 6
rot2 6 7 4
4 7 6 
7 4 6 
6 7 4 
rot1 3 1 2
rot2 2 3 1
4 7 6 
3 1 2 
2 3 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing pointers to local variables when you do this kind of thing:

```
modList->push_back(&rot1);
```

These get invalidated every loop cycle. You could save yourself a lot of trouble by not storing pointers in the first place.

Comment: But vectors save a copy of the pointer if I am not wrong and each time it would be a new pointer. Does it have any problem?

Comment: @tariqzafar the problem is not the pointers, but where they point to.

Comment: I had one more general query. In case my struct is big and I dont want it to be copied and rather want to use a vector of pointers. How can I do it above without doing any memory leaks?